# Extracting all polygons from GeoTIFF raster layer as PNG images using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, extract, png

I have a GeoTIFF file with multiple separated polygons on it as the following:

[image]

I'd like to find a way of extracting all these polygons as separated individual PNG images, just so I can have them as different images inside a folder.

Is there any way of doing something like this with QGIS using the GeoTIFF layer (I also have these polygons in a vector layer)?

Answer (score 1):

Export each vector polygon to its own separate, single-polygon layer.  Then rasterize each of those layers to a tiff.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you'd do that exactly? This idea works in theory but for my particular case, I haven't managed to make it work. If I use the option `split vector layer` inside the `Processing Toolbox` I end up splitting my single layer into 4000 layers. Then I don't even manage to open all those layers at once on QGIS to accomplish the next step.